# updating database in my sql using java

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I have a problem in updating a database in MySQL using java.To be specific this problem occurs after I update a score(the last score from a GUI Interface).The update is successful but when I attempt to retrieve the updated record.It gives me a null pointer exception(sets the value of the picture of the record to null).Because of the amount of code written,I decided to insert just the code I wrote for the update of the database.The major problem am having is after update of the last record in the database,when the record is being retrieved the value of the picture is set to null and this gives me a java.lang.null Pointer Exception.Please help me out here.Thanks in advance.
   Code for update

```
 private void upActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   

 //checks if user wants to update an empty field or record.   
    if ( m.equals("") || f.equals("") || l.equals("") || g.equals("") || d.equals("") || p.equals("") || a.equals("")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all the details");

    }else if(fi.equals("")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please re-update picture");
    }
    else{
   int confirmUpdate = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to update this record?", "Confirm Update", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
     if (confirmUpdate == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ass1", "root", "root");
//SQL update statement to update record based on prmary key mn.
            ps = con.prepareStatement("Update Student SET fn=?,ln=?,gn=?,dp=?,pn=?,ad=?,mt=?,ph=?,ch=?,zo=?,pp=?,pc=?,pz=?,tt=?,av=?,gd=?,re=?,pic=?,fil=? Where mn='" + m + "'");


            ps.setString(1, f);
            ps.setString(2, l);
            ps.setString(3, g);
            ps.setString(4, d);
            ps.setString(5, p);
            ps.setString(6, a);

            ps.setString(7, h);
            ps.setString(8, s);
            ps.setString(9, i);
            ps.setString(10, y);
            ps.setString(11, yp);
            ps.setString(12, pm);
            ps.setString(13, zp);
            ps.setString(14, al);
            ps.setString(15, ge);
            ps.setString(16, de);
            ps.setString(17, rk);

            ps.setBytes(18, pi);
            ps.setString(19, fi);

            ps.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Updated Successfully", "Data Updated", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            dispose();
         new view().setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + e);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

please note that the variable for the last record that is being changed which results in the null pointer exception is rk. This is calculated from the last record indicated as variable  zp.Hope my question is clear.Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using "where mn = '"+xyz+"'' if you're using "fn=?"

Comment: I am not using fn, I am updating "fn" based on the value of "mn", which is the primary key. Thanks.

Comment: ok, let me put this way. why are you using the safe proper way of assigning variables with prepared statements for fn and using the unsafe and susceptible to sql injection way of concatenating strings for mn? :-)

Comment: please suggest a better way. Thanks.

Comment: Update Student SET fn=?,ln=?,gn=?,dp=?,pn=?,ad=?,mt=?,ph=?,ch=?,zo=?,pp=?,pc=?,pz=?,tt=?,av=?,gd=?,re=?,pic=?,fil=? Where mn=?

Answer (score 0):

```
"Update Student SET fn=?,ln=?,gn=?,dp=?,pn=?,ad=?,mt=?,ph=?,ch=?,
zo=?,pp=?,pc=?,pz=?,tt=?,av=?,gd=?,re=?,pic=?,fil=? 
Where mn='"
```

I can't see RK in the UPDATE command, even tried find by Ctrl-F with no success.

Comment: Hi, the rk is not in the update command, but it's in the "ps.setString" statements. the variable that equals the rk in the update command is "re".